# Libreoffice is not starting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: libreoffice

I tried

```
sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

But it is not working. Does anyone have any solution?

Edit

I am not able to find the correct log file in Ubuntu that should provide the error. When I execute from the Terminal `libreoffice --writer` I only receive the message `Application Error`

Comment: It should be `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa`

Comment: It starts opening but the process stops without any explanation. I tried from the terminal [libreoffice fileName.xls] and I received the answer [Application Error]

Comment: You need to edit your question and copy and paste exact terminal errors you are getting.  Without this info we can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: It only says "Application Error". Is there a way to acess the log file?

Comment: Normally found in the `/var/log/dpkg.log` file.

Comment: Start in Terminal and give the result. Maybe you will see some error message then.

Comment: @davidbaumann I have already done this. The only message is "Application Error".

Comment: @Terrance in this file, I believe the only information in this file is about the installation and not the errors

Comment: Do you want to try 6.0? https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-6-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my solution as answer, so the question can be set to answered:

As you want to use a newer version of libreoffice, you can try version 6.0.

https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/libreoffice-6-0